# PHP Elasticsearch search at the start of a string

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a table of products in a MySql database and I want to search their product name and description.

All works well if I type the full name of the product into the search but it doesn't break the term down into parts. For example it will find products for the term 'pioneer' but won't find anything for 'pio' or 'pionee'.

I guess I'm either building the index incorrectly or doing the search incorrectly?

I'm creating my index like so:

```
$params = [
        'index' => 'products',
        'type' => 'product',
        'body' => [
            'settings' => [
                'analysis' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'ngram_filter' =>  [
                            "type" => "ngram",
                            "min_gram" => 1,
                            "max_gram" => 10
                        ]
                    ],
                    'analyzer' => [
                        'ngram_analyzer' => [
                            "type" => "custom",
                            "tokenizer" => "standard",
                            "filter" => [
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding",
                                "ngram_filter"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'mappings' => [
                'products' => [
                    'name' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'include_in_all' => true,
                        'analyzer' => 'ngram_analyzer',
                        'search_analyzer' => 'standard'
                    ],
                    'description' => [
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'include_in_all' => true,
                        'analyzer' => 'ngram_analyzer',
                        'search_analyzer' => 'standard'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

I'm indexing the DB results like this:

```
 foreach($products as $product){

        $params = [
            'index' => 'products',
            'type' => 'product',
            'id' => $product['id'],
            'body' => [
                'name' => $product['name'],
                'description' => $product['description']
            ]
        ];

        $response = $client->index($params);
        var_dump($response);
    }
```

And then to search I'm doing the following:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'products',
    'type' => 'product',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'name' => $term
            ],
            'match' => [
                'description' => $term
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$response = $client->search($params);


foreach($response['hits']['hits'] as $result){
    echo $result['_source']['name'] . '<br>';
}

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Have you tried checking what your terms look like with the [_analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/indices-analyze.html)?

Comment: @Tim honestly no, the PHP docs are very thin on the ground past the basics. Does the set-up look correct above?

Comment: I'm not real familiar with PHP, but if you don't want to use curl you should be able to use a [serializer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/6.0/_serializers.html#_serialize) to send json to Elastic. That would allow you to use the _analyze API. As far as your set up, I would look into your ngrams again. Usually they recommend the min and max to be within 1 of each other, or the same. I would start with trigrams (min 3 and max 3).